# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid when creating new bitmap c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, argument-error

When calling this function multiple times, either of the try blocks keep throwing the errors. This occurs at random times especially when calling repeatedly.

```
//CameraCanvas: Class bitmap variable
//Canvas: Class bitmap imported through open file dialog

public void UpdateCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            CameraCanvas = new Bitmap(CameraWidthHeight.X, CameraWidthHeight.Y, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(CameraCanvas);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        //Draw it
        Bitmap drawImage = Canvas;
        g.DrawImage(drawImage, new PointF(0f,0f));
        try
        {
            CameraCanvas = new Bitmap(CameraWidthHeight.X, CameraWidthHeight.Y, g);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

I have tried so many things but none of them work. None of the code involve stream or anything like that. Below is the code for importing the Canvas as a bitmap through open file dialog in the form constructor.

```
        Bitmap source;
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            if(of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                source = new Bitmap(of.FileName);
                Canvas = source;
                this.TopLevel = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the image is not valid.  Maybe the image file is locked.  Maybe you're leaking memory.

Comment: Try :  Image image =  Image.FromFile("filename"); Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);

Comment: @Edson Ho  `Canvas = source;` <- this is not good, you should dereference it with `Canvas = new Bitmap(source);`. Then, after you assign it `Bitmap drawImage = Canvas;`, `.Dispose()` of it.